# Using Eclipse to run/debug python when source files are encoded in Latin-1 (=ISO-8859-1)

Tags: python, eclipse, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to get Eclipse (Kepler) to run and debug a python project where my source files contain some non-ASCII characters, and are encoded using Latin-1 (=ISO-8859-1).

I can get it to work if I convert the files to UTF8 or add a comment in the beginning of the files like

```python
# -*- coding: Latin-1 -*-
```

but my problem is that ***I don't wan't to change the source files*** in any way, for various reasons (the files are version managed and used in a very specific way etc.).

I just want Eclipse to assume that the source files are Latin-1 encoded unless otherwise specified (by an initial comment in the source file, like above). But my Eclipse seems to only assume UTF8 when any characters are non-ASCII. I've set the Project->Properties->Resource->Text file encoding to ISO-8859-1 but it doesn't seem to help for the source files.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does 'Properties > Resource' say for the encoding for an actual source file?

Comment: According to [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) the default is supposed to be ASCII, so it must be setting the encoding somehow if it accepts UTF-8. I suspect the text file encoding property only applies to the editor, not Python itself.

Comment: When I, in Eclipse, right-click the actual files and go Properties->Resource, it says "Text file encoding" is "Default (inherited from container: ISO-8859-1)", which looks right, and the non-ASCII chars do appear correctly in the editor. It's just that I can't run or debug.

Comment: See if this helps: https://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/

Comment: The Encoding under the Common tab in Run Configurations also says ISO-8859-1, so that too looks just about right :-(